# Getting Error: "HTTP GET failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am starting to learn writing Office Addins with Javascript. I have spent alot time on MS website going through tutorials and documentation. I figure I would try my hand on a few of the Addin walk throughs.

I am using VS Code with Node.js. After having successfully creating a few examples and worked through the creation process.

I figure I would step up the debug environment so I could really get into the learning/development phase. I followed the instructions on the following MS webpage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-with-vs-extension using my functioning addin example.

When I start the debugger inside VS Code, I get the following error:

> Discovering targets via http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/list HTTP GET
> failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222

I am assuming I have a configuration problem somewhere, I have search for these errors but haven't found anyone out there that has experienced this problem.

Any suggests would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this [vscode-chrome-debug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/356) help?

Comment: No I think that example is calling adifferent debugger iterface, this the example of the JSON params that the install was telling you to use. {
  "type": "office-addin",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach to Office Add-ins",
  "port": 9222,
  "trace": "verbose",
  "url": "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html?_host_Info=HOST$Win32$16.01$en-US$$$$0",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "timeout": 45000
}